# Display Tournament League from total Players

Tags: java, performance, algorithm

I've created function that will display a league competition from the total team numbers.

For example if we have 4 teams it will display `(a vs b) vs (c vs d)` 
and if we have 5 teams it will diplay `((a vs b) vs c) vs (d vs e)` and so on. It will display the competition looks square or equal.

here is the complete code :

```
public class EqualPlayer {
    private int index=0;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        EqualPlayer equalPlayer = new EqualPlayer();
        System.out.println(equalPlayer.getEqualPlayerID(26));
    }


    private String getEqualPlayerID(int numberPlayers){
        int nPDevided = numberPlayers/2;
        int A = numberPlayers-nPDevided;
        int B = nPDevided;
        String result="";

        if(A>2 || B > 2)
            return "( "+getEqualPlayerID(A)+" )"+" vs "+ "( "+getEqualPlayerID(B)+" )";

        if(A==2)
            if(result.isEmpty()){
                result = "( "+ getPlayerId(index) +" vs " +getPlayerId(index+1) +" )";
                index+=2;
            }
            else{
                result =  result+" vs ( "+getPlayerId(index)+" vs "+ getPlayerId(index+1) +" )";
                index+=2;
            }
        else if(A==1)
            if(result.isEmpty()){
                result = ""+getPlayerId(index);
                index+=1;
            }
            else{
                result = result+" vs "+ getPlayerId(index);
                index+=1;
            }

        if(B==2)
            if(result.isEmpty()){
                result = "( "+ getPlayerId(index) +" vs " +getPlayerId(index+1) +" )";
                index+=2;
            }
            else{
                result =  result+" vs ( "+getPlayerId(index)+" vs "+ getPlayerId(index+1) +" )";
                index+=2;
            }
        else if(B ==1)
            if(result.isEmpty()){
                result = ""+getPlayerId(index);
                index+=1;
            }
            else{
                result = result+" vs "+ getPlayerId(index);
                index+=1;
            }


        return result;

    }


    private char getPlayerId(int index){
        char [] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
        return  alphabet[index];
    }

}
```

Any better idea how to create this function without recursive?

And also the limits of the player is 26 which is the total alphabets, if I want to increase the total player I need to add additional char to `getPlayerId` method, I would like to know about what are you guys think about that?
Improvement, suggestion, are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clean up your code by looking for similarities and getting rid of the duplication by creating separate functions. I'll demonstrate.

---

Let's take a look at this bit:

```
    if(A==2)
        if(result.isEmpty()){
            result = "( "+ getPlayerId(index) +" vs " +getPlayerId(index+1) +" )";
            index+=2;
        }
        else{
            result =  result+" vs ( "+getPlayerId(index)+" vs "+ getPlayerId(index+1) +" )";
            index+=2;
        }
    else if(A==1)
        if(result.isEmpty()){
            result = ""+getPlayerId(index);
            index+=1;
        }
        else{
            result = result+" vs "+ getPlayerId(index);
            index+=1;
        }

    if(B==2)
        if(result.isEmpty()){
            result = "( "+ getPlayerId(index) +" vs " +getPlayerId(index+1) +" )";
            index+=2;
        }
        else{
            result =  result+" vs ( "+getPlayerId(index)+" vs "+ getPlayerId(index+1) +" )";
            index+=2;
        }
    else if(B ==1)
        if(result.isEmpty()){
            result = ""+getPlayerId(index);
            index+=1;
        }
        else{
            result = result+" vs "+ getPlayerId(index);
            index+=1;
        }
```

Step 1 - add braces.

```
    if(A==2){
        if(result.isEmpty()){
            result = "( "+ getPlayerId(index) +" vs " +getPlayerId(index+1) +" )";
            index+=2;
        }
        else{
            result =  result+" vs ( "+getPlayerId(index)+" vs "+ getPlayerId(index+1) +" )";
            index+=2;
        }
    } else if(A==1) {
        if(result.isEmpty()){
            result = ""+getPlayerId(index);
            index+=1;
        }
        else{
            result = result+" vs "+ getPlayerId(index);
            index+=1;
        }
    }
    if(B==2){
        if(result.isEmpty()){
            result = "( "+ getPlayerId(index) +" vs " +getPlayerId(index+1) +" )";
            index+=2;
        }
        else{
            result =  result+" vs ( "+getPlayerId(index)+" vs "+ getPlayerId(index+1) +" )";
            index+=2;
        }
    } else if(B == 1){
        if(result.isEmpty()){
            result = ""+getPlayerId(index);
            index+=1;
        }
        else{
            result = result+" vs "+ getPlayerId(index);
            index+=1;
        }
    }
```

Step 2 - identify sections of duplicate code and generalize them.

In your case, this is the `index+=2` and `index+=1` at the end of each case.

```
    if(A==2){
        if(result.isEmpty()){
            result = "( "+ getPlayerId(index) +" vs " +getPlayerId(index+1) +" )";
        }
        else{
            result =  result+" vs ( "+getPlayerId(index)+" vs "+ getPlayerId(index+1) +" )";
        }
        index+=2;
    } else if(A==1) {
        if(result.isEmpty()){
            result = ""+getPlayerId(index);
        }
        else{
            result = result+" vs "+ getPlayerId(index);
        }
        index+=1;
    }
    if(B==2){
        if(result.isEmpty()){
            result = "( "+ getPlayerId(index) +" vs " +getPlayerId(index+1) +" )";
        }
        else{
            result =  result+" vs ( "+getPlayerId(index)+" vs "+ getPlayerId(index+1) +" )";
        }
        index+=2;
    } else if(B == 1){
        if(result.isEmpty()){
            result = ""+getPlayerId(index);
        }
        else{
            result = result+" vs "+ getPlayerId(index);
        }
        index+=1;
    }
```

Next, further reduce the duplicate code. You can see that if `B` is 2, we'll add 2 to index. If `B` is 1, we'll add 1 to index. We can just add `B` to index. (We're reducing duplication of constants here)

```
    if(A==2){
        if(result.isEmpty()){
            result = "( "+ getPlayerId(index) +" vs " +getPlayerId(index+1) +" )";
        }
        else{
            result =  result+" vs ( "+getPlayerId(index)+" vs "+ getPlayerId(index+1) +" )";
        }
        index+=A;
    } else if(A==1) {
        if(result.isEmpty()){
            result = ""+getPlayerId(index);
        }
        else{
            result = result+" vs "+ getPlayerId(index);
        }
        index+=A;
    }
    if(B==2){
        if(result.isEmpty()){
            result = "( "+ getPlayerId(index) +" vs " +getPlayerId(index+1) +" )";
        }
        else{
            result =  result+" vs ( "+getPlayerId(index)+" vs "+ getPlayerId(index+1) +" )";
        }
        index+=B;
    } else if(B == 1){
        if(result.isEmpty()){
            result = ""+getPlayerId(index);
        }
        else{
            result = result+" vs "+ getPlayerId(index);
        }
        index+=B;
    }
```

Next, remove duplication by creating a separate function that allows you to create the `"( "+ getPlayerId(index) +" vs " +getPlayerId(index+1) +" )"` part in one call.

```
private String printVersus(int startIndex){
    return "( "+ getPlayerId(index) +" vs " +getPlayerId(index+1) +" )";
}
```

Then, use it.

```
    if(A==2){
        if(result.isEmpty()){
            result = printVersus(index);
        }
        else{
            result = result+" vs "+printVersus(index);
        }
        index+=A;
    } else if(A==1) {
        if(result.isEmpty()){
            result = ""+getPlayerId(index);
        }
        else{
            result = result+" vs "+ getPlayerId(index);
        }
        index+=A;
    }
    if(B==2){
        if(result.isEmpty()){
            result = printVersus(index);
        }
        else{
            result =  result+" vs "+printVersus(index);
        }
        index+=B;
    } else if(B == 1){
        if(result.isEmpty()){
            result = ""+getPlayerId(index);
        }
        else{
            result = result+" vs "+ getPlayerId(index);
        }
        index+=B;
    }
```

Next, once again identify that there is duplication in handling of string appending - you handle `result.isEmpty()` in multiple places. Create a separate function. I gave it a bit of a poor name, since I haven't actually checked your business logic yet - I'm just optimizing this based on patterns!

```
private String appendVersusString(String original, String toAdd){
    if(original.isEmpty()){
        return toAdd;
    }
    else{
        return original+" vs "+ toAdd;
    }
}
```

Use the new function.

```
    if(A==2){
        result = appendVersusString(result, printVersus(index));
        index+=A;
    } else if(A==1) {
        result = appendVersusString(result, ""+getPlayerId(index));
        index+=A;
    }
    if(B==2){
        result = appendVersusString(result, printVersus(index));
        index+=B;
    } else if(B == 1){
        result = appendVersusString(result, ""+getPlayerId(index));
        index+=B;
    }
```

Once again, spot duplication between A and B - they're doing the exact same at the end of the case. I am assuming that A and B cannot go into the negatives.

Since `if(A>2 || B > 2)` has an early return, A and B are (individually) either 2, 1, or 0.

Thus we can see that if A is 2, we add A. If A is 1, we add A. If A is 0, we don't add anything. Same goes for B.

So we can just do `index+=A` in all three cases.

```
    if(A==2){
        result = appendVersusString(result, printVersus(index));
    } else if(A==1) {
        result = appendVersusString(result, ""+getPlayerId(index));
    }
    index+=A;
    if(B==2){
        result = appendVersusString(result, printVersus(index));
    } else if(B == 1){
        result = appendVersusString(result, ""+getPlayerId(index));
    }
    index+=B;
```

There is still duplication in the handling of A and B when it comes to `appendVersusString`. I think they're "groups", so I'll name the function `handleGroup`:

```
private String handleGroup(String result, int group, int currentIndex){
    if(group==2){
        result = appendVersusString(result, printVersus(currentIndex));
    } else if(group == 1) {
        result = appendVersusString(result, ""+getPlayerId(currentIndex));
    }
    return result;
}
```

And use your new function.

```
    handleGroup(result, A, index);
    index+=A;
    handleGroup(result, B, index);
    index+=B;
```

Final result:

```
public class EqualPlayer {
    private int index=0;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        EqualPlayer equalPlayer = new EqualPlayer();
        System.out.println(equalPlayer.getEqualPlayerID(26));
    }


    private String getEqualPlayerID(int numberPlayers){
        int nPDevided = numberPlayers/2;
        int A = numberPlayers-nPDevided;
        int B = nPDevided;
        String result="";

        if(A>2 || B > 2)
            return "( "+getEqualPlayerID(A)+" )"+" vs "+ "( "+getEqualPlayerID(B)+" )";

        handleGroup(result, A, index);
        index+=A;
        handleGroup(result, B, index);
        index+=B;

        return result;
    }

    private String handleGroup(String result, int group, int currentIndex){
        if(group==2){
            result = appendVersusString(result, printVersus(currentIndex));
        } else if(group == 1) {
            result = appendVersusString(result, ""+getPlayerId(currentIndex));
        }
        return result;
    }

    private String appendVersusString(String original, String toAdd){
        if(original.isEmpty()){
            return toAdd;
        }
        else{
            return original+" vs "+ toAdd;
        }
    }

    private String printVersus(int startIndex){
        return "( "+ getPlayerId(index) +" vs " +getPlayerId(index+1) +" )";
    }

    private char getPlayerId(int index){
        char [] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
        return  alphabet[index];
    }

}
```

---

Lastly, you could consider using a `StringBuilder` to prevent needless copying of String contents. I also recommend putting spaces around operators to improve readability (`if(A == 2)` instead of `if(A==2)` and `index += A` instead of `index+=A`).

Comment: wow you're really awesome, thank you for answer sir!. I wish I could add 100 upvote for this

Comment: and by the way is it possible solve this problem without using recursive? since I'm looking another possible solution for this also, I would love to hear your thought.

Comment: @GujaratSantana Recursive is a very natural solution for this case. I know there's a non-recursive solution possible (using a loop and making use of the binary form of a number, but I don't feel like explaining myself fully (would take a lot of time).

Comment: @GujaratSantana look at binary trees and binary representation of a number, see if you can do anything interesting with "the number of players" and "how does a binary tree with <number of players> leaves look"

Comment: alright cool I'll have a look, thanks for the suggestion I  couldn't figure it out how to solve this without recursive. will do this later

Comment: @GujaratSantana to be honest I don't have a good idea either, my recursive solution is making my own "call stack" which is ... bad - essentially recursive but all in the same function